# Should I include mix app in extra_applications?

Tags: elixir, distillery

I'm using distillery to package an elixir application, and I want to have access to the current environment in the runtime (is it `:dev`, `:test` or :prod).

The goal will be checking the env at the runtime, something like this:

```
if Mix.env() == :prod do
  # do this only in production
end
```

What are the drawbacks of including the `mix` app in the release?

```
def application do
    [mod: {EvercamMedia, []}, extra_applications: [:runtime_tools, :os_mon, :recon, :mix]]
end
```

Comment: Why would you want to do it in the first place?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I want to execute some functions only in the prod environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `mix` to detect the production environment is clearly an antipattern. Instead, one should probably start the release as

```sh
MY_APP_PROD=true release start
```

and use the system environment check as shown below

```elixir
if System.get_env("MY_APP_PROD") == "true" do
  ...
end
```

Comment: This can be evaluated at compile-time if not used inside of a function.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose we all can tell what’s evaluated when :)

Comment: maybe you can, but it is a good practice to ensure that everybody understands, even beginners.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin It's not obvious to me why it's antipattern, can you  elaborate more on this point please?

Comment: It’s an antipattern because `mix` has never been designed to properly work in `prod` runtime, it’s a compile-time beast.

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* include `mix` in your release. You have various alternatives:

- Use an environment variable, which is set at runtime, and then either:

  - Check it in code using e.g. `System.fetch_env!`.
  - Check it in `config/runtime.exs` (*not* `config/prod.exs`; this is also evaluated at compile-time).
- Or compile the value of `MIX_ENV` into your code. @Daniel provides one way to do this. I offer another:

```
defmodule M do
  @build_env Mix.env()

  def env(), do: @build_env
end
```

The trick here is that the `@build_env...` statement is evaluated at compile-time (when Mix *is* available), setting the attribute. You can then just return it from your function.

Answer (score 0):

Mix is disabled in production for a reason, it is a build tool, you can read more about it [here](https://elixirforum.com/t/mix-project-missing-in-elixir-phoenix-prod-release/11413/2?u=d4no0).

If you need only the current environment, then you can do something like this:

```
defmacro env() do
    quote do
      unquote(Mix.env())
    end
  end
```

However you need to remember that this code is evaluated at **compile-time** and will not work with things like [runtime](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/config-and-releases.html) configurations.